# Динамически исполняемые скрипты на QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Посоветуйте пожалуйста как подступиться к довольно специфической задаче интеграции `c++` с `qml`.

**Упрощенно задача следующая**

Имеется приложение на `Qt Widgets` и объектная модель на `C++`, где каждый объект является наследником `QObject` и имеет базовый класс с функцией получения значения его свойств:

```
QVariant getValue(const QString& valueName) const;
```

Необходимо создать механизм написания проверочных формул, которые объединяются в "контрольный лист". Сам класс "Контрольный лист" должен быть на `C++` и работать следующим образом:

1. На вход контрольному листу подается набор указанных выше объектов, каждому из которых присваивается уникальный код
2. Контрольный лист содержит список редактируемых пользователем формул на `qml`. Каждая формула должна выполнить некие проверки переданных объектов, определяя их по стандартным кодам и на основании запросов к функции `getValue`, и сообщить пройдена ли проверка. Если не пройдена, то сообщить текст ошибки.
3. По итогам прогона всех формул имеем список результатов прогона каждой формулы, который надо обрабатывать далее на `С++`.

С `qml` ранее дела не имел, но в теории представляю что надо для начала запихнуть все объекты контроля в контекст `QQmlEngine` и дальше как-то с ними работать, но даже не пойму с какой стороны подступиться к динамическому запуску формул на `qml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечаю на свой же вопрос :)

Для решения данной задачи `QML` не нужен. Достаточно использовать встроенный в `QML` движок `javascript`: `QJSEngine`. Он как раз и позволяет запускать на выполнение произвольные формулы. Передача внутрь формулы `c++` объектов также возможна, при этом они должны соответствовать тем же требованиям, что и для передачи их внутрь `qml` (наследование от `QObject`, `Q_INVOKABLE`, `Q_PROPERTY` и т.п.)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете объявить методы c++ сделав их доступными из `QML`, так же вы можете пробросить сигналы из плюсов в `QML`. И в `QML` по сигналу окончания обработки брать результат из функции `c++`. Короткий пример функции доступной из `QML` приведен ниже, и взят из документации где все это подробно описано, с документации и начинайте.
`QQmlEngine` нужен для других целей - для создания самого интерфейса `QML` из кода C++ 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html

```
class MessageBoard : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE bool postMessage(const QString &msg) {
        qDebug() << "Called the C++ method with" << msg;
        return true;
    }

public slots:
    void refresh() {
        qDebug() << "Called the C++ slot";
    }
};
```

Для обратного взаимодействия -вы можете получать свойства QML объектов в c++,  описано тут

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html

Пример вызова функции QML из c++
QML:
    // MyItem.qml
    import QtQuick 2.0

```
Item {
    function myQmlFunction(msg) {
        console.log("Got message:", msg)
        return "some return value"
    }
}
```

C++

```
// main.cpp
QQmlEngine engine;
QQmlComponent component(&engine, "MyItem.qml");
QObject *object = component.create();

QVariant returnedValue;
QVariant msg = "Hello from C++";
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(object, "myQmlFunction",
        Q_RETURN_ARG(QVariant, returnedValue),
        Q_ARG(QVariant, msg));

qDebug() << "QML function returned:" << returnedValue.toString();
delete object;
```

Comment: Но мне надо чтобы можно было править скрипты функций без пересборки проекта. Для этого же надо их как-то динамически подгружать. Видимо через `QQmlComponent::loadUrl`. Но тогда разве реально обойтись без `QQmlEngine`?

Comment: Вы можете нужные функции вынести в QML, но, это нарушит разделение представления и контроллера, и может иметь последствия в будущем (программа потеряет гибкость, представление будет сильно связно с контроллером) QQmlEngine вам конечно нужен, чтоб из плюсов создать QML объект графический.

Comment: Мне не нужна графика. Приложение изначально сделано на `Qt Widgets`. От `QML` мне нужна исключительно возможность динамического запуска на обработку кода на javascript. Не писать же свой язык формул, если уже есть готовый.

Comment: Ох, тогда вам возможно поможет эта ссылка, про доступ к QML объектам из плюсов  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html, но для описанных вами целей QML не используется, хотя попробовать никогда не зря :)

Comment: Написал ответ выше: для этой задачи нужен `QJSEngine`, а не `QQmlEngine`

Comment: Вот это я думаю и правда правильное решение :) QML он для интерфейсов